# User input with timeout doesn't work as hoped

Tags: asynchronous, promise, user-input, raku

Why don't loop cycles work as before after a timeout (no more printed user input)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

loop {
    my $str;
    my $timeout = Promise.in( 5 ).then({
        $str = 'Timeout';
    });
    my $user = Promise.start({
        $str = prompt '>';
    });
    await Promise.anyof( $timeout, $user );
    if $str eq 'q' {
        last;
    }
    say "[$str]";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're talking to the wrong call to `prompt`, which is in a promise which has closed on a different variable `$str`.  The second and later calls to `prompt` block, waiting for the first call to finish.  But the `$str` that is to receive the value of the first call is out of scope, so nothing happens.

That sounds very strange, but here's an experiment you can run to help your intuition along while I dissect it more fully:  run the script, wait for the timeout, then enter `q` twice in rapid succession.  The script quits after the second one.  Why?

On the first loop, we declare a variable `$str` which I'm going to call "`$str` number 1" and create a `Promise` that closes over `$str` number 1 and calls `prompt`.  `prompt` attaches to `STDIN` and doesn't return until it sees a newline.  When the timeout expires, that call to `prompt` is not interrupted.  It's still running.  Still waiting.  The promise it's attached to (let's call it `$user` promise 1) is still active even though the variable `$user` is about to go out of scope.

On the second loop, we declare a new variable `$str` ("`$str` number 2"), create a `Promise` that closes over *it*, and call `prompt` again.  But another call to `prompt` is still using `STDIN`, so the new call blocks and waits for `STDIN` to become available.  If you type something now, it will be seen by the original call to `prompt`, which was attached to `$user` promise 1 and closed over `$str` number 1.

`$str` number 1 is updated when `prompt` returns, but it doesn't matter because you stopped looking at it.  The `if $str eq 'q'` conditional is going to inspect `$str` number 2, because that's the variable that was declared in the current loop.

The second call to `prompt` then immediately asks for input, and if you type `q` before the timeout expires, it updates the version of `$str` that it closed over, `$str` number 2.  Since that's the one your conditional is inspecting, the loop terminates.

Every timeout starts a new `prompt` without terminating the old one, which means that the input the user types is never attached to the same `$str` that you are inspecting.  Even if you inspect the original variable, the subsequent calls to `prompt` still happen and will keep prompting even after execution has left the block.

Since `prompt` doesn't have a way to specify a timeout and Raku doesn't have a way to "kill" scheduled `Promises`, I don't think you get to solve this problem with `prompt`.

Answer (score 3):

The logical issue in this code, is that the timeout Promise *will* trigger after 5 seconds, even if someone has entered something in the previous iteration.  And so it will set `$str` at seemingly random times.

There is a simple solution: just make sure that you do *not* assign `$str` in the timeout code if it has already been set:

```
$str //= 'Timeout';
```

For this example, it doesn't really matter, but generally you don't want code to be executing willy nilly, so it would be better to actually de-activate the `Promise`.  Unfortunately, you cannot do that with the `Promise` interface.  But the `Promise.in` method is actually a wrapper around the `ThreadPoolScheduler.cue` method, which *does* return a `Cancellation` object (https://docs.raku.org/routine/cue).

Comment: When I replace the 6. line of my example with `$str //= 'Timeout'` I don't see any changes in the outcome of the script.

Comment: Then maybe you should describe the outcome of your script more precisely?

Comment: After a triggered timeout a user-input of `q` no longer quits the script even with `$str //= 'Timeout'`.